# How to transform dataframe into the sample?

Tags: python, pandas

I am hesitating how to make the following changes in my dataframe
I have this table:
[List1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol8qP.png)

I need to transform it to this:
[List2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNqGP.png)

Could you please help me with it? I know how to fill in the column segment, but it is not enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please try copy paste the data for flexibility

Comment: The answer likely involves `pivot_table`, though we'd need a sample of the data as text to experiment with.

Comment: `df.pivot_table(values=['sales2017','sales2018'],index='category', columns=['Segment'])` hope it works for you